# Achieving multiple Values under one column in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

Greetings I am new to Power BI, and have fallen in love. I seek guidance for a module I'm attempting to create and I’m not coming across anything as straight forward as my question—

I work for a SaaS company where our clients can have multiple concurrent contracts. I need to display all upcoming renewals/expiring contracts in ascending order.

Currently, the data is stored as exhibited in the 1st image below. For the table I am looking to achieve (2nd one), I need all of the expiring contract dates to fall into one column, and the contract type (the header in image 1) to reflect as it's own column. Anyone with more than one contract will be listed more than once.

Currently, the data looks like this:
[image: Client list & their Expiring Contract Dates]

Instead, I seek to achieve this:
[image: All Contract Expiration Dates in one column for sorting purposes]

Is this possible?  Please let me know if there are any questions!

Comment: You should unpivot the data in Power Query. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/unpivot-column

Answer (score 0):

Edit: First of all, it is not clear to me if every contract is in different column or are all together under the same column. If the latter, you may follow the below. If the former, please let me know as David's comment is valid and this does not apply and I will need to delete this reply. -- End of edit.

Please try and use a Matrix Visual instead of a table visual. Then you can add both values in rows and show them in a tabular form.

Below are the data that I used:

[image]

And here is the visual that I achieved is by putting on the rows the sub and contr variables and in the values the renewal and amnt variables.

Then you just need to expand all down one level from within the visual:
[image]

And finally you turn off the stepped layout by going row headers -> options:

[image]

Voila:

[image]

You can also refer to [this](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Display-data-in-matrix-Visual-like-tabular-format/m-p/490981) URL.

Comment: Thank you!  I am reviewing this now and will advise!

Comment: Thanks, let me know if this is what you needed and if so please accept the solution.

P.